# Regular expression is not working for specific number

Tags: java, regex

I have the regular expression needs to accept the value 6-240.

```
[6-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-3][0-9]|240
```

It is working fine for value from 6-239, but not 240.

I have tried

```
0*([6-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-3][0-9]|240)
([6-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-3][0-9]|240).
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what pattern do you expect.

Comment: Whatever you do, it looks like you would be far better off to parse this as an Integer and check the range.

Comment: [Now it works!](http://regex101.com/r/uN2fL9/1)

Comment: This is neater: if (x == (int)x) { if (i > 5 && i < 241) { ... } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?:(?:[6-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-3][0-9])|240)$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/37

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
([6-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-3][0-9])|240
```